# Error: ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property has not been initialized. (Trying to connect with Snowflake DB using script task of SSIS)

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Requesting your help on below error.
Error: ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property has not been initialized.

I am trying to connect with snowflake DB using script task of SSIS using CSharp code. I have created the connection successfully in connection manager in SSIS and using same connection in C-Sharp code to perform some SQL operation on Snowflake DB. but getting above error in below line.

CreateTableCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();--- error coming on this code

Can somebody please help as I am new to C-Sharp. Also same code is working when change connection of Snowflake to SqlServer.

```
   public void Main() {
        string FolderPath = Dts.Variables["User::FolderPath"].Value.ToString();
        string TableName = Dts.Variables["User::TableName"].Value.ToString();
        string SchemaName = Dts.Variables["User::SchemaName"].Value.ToString();
        // string StartingColumn = Dts.Variables["User::StartingColumn"].Value.ToString();
        // string EndingColumn = Dts.Variables["User::EndingColumn"].Value.ToString();
        //  string StartReadingFromRow = Dts.Variables["User::StartReadingFromRow"].Value.ToString();
        var directory = new DirectoryInfo(FolderPath);
        FileInfo[] files = directory.GetFiles();

        //Declare and initilize variables
        string fileFullPath = "";

        //Get one Book(Excel file at a time)
        foreach (FileInfo file in files)
        {
            fileFullPath = FolderPath + "\\" + file.Name;

            //Create Excel Connection
            string ConStr;
            string HDR;
            HDR = "YES";
            ConStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + fileFullPath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=" + HDR + ";IMEX=0\"";
            OleDbConnection cnn = new OleDbConnection(ConStr);

            //MessageBox.Show(TableName);
            //Get Sheet Name
            cnn.Open();
            DataTable dtSheet = cnn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);

            //string sheetname;
            //sheetname = "";

            //foreach (DataRow drSheet in dtSheet.Rows)
            //{
            //if (drSheet["TABLE_NAME"].ToString().Contains("$"))
            //{
            //    sheetname = drSheet["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();

            //Load the DataTable with Sheet Data so we can get the column header
            //OleDbCommand oconn = new OleDbCommand("select top 1 * from [" + sheetname + StartingColumn + StartReadingFromRow + ":" + EndingColumn + "]", cnn);
            OleDbCommand oconn = new OleDbCommand("select top 1 * from [Part_D_Cut_Points$]", cnn);


            OleDbDataAdapter adp = new OleDbDataAdapter(oconn);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            adp.Fill(dt);
            cnn.Close();

            int ColumnCount = dt.Columns.Count;

            //Prepare Header columns list so we can run against Database to get matching columns for a table.
            string ExcelHeaderColumn = "";
            String SelectColumn = "";

            //string GetHeader ColumnsList to Create Table= "";
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                String check = dt.Columns[i].ColumnName;

                if (i != dt.Columns.Count - 1)
                    ExcelHeaderColumn += "[" + dt.Columns[i].ColumnName + "] NVarchar(150) NULL" + ",";
                else
                    ExcelHeaderColumn += "[" + dt.Columns[i].ColumnName + "] NVarchar(150) NULL";
            }


            //string GetSelect ColumnsList Fetch data from ExcelTable "";
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                if (i != dt.Columns.Count - 1)
                    SelectColumn += "[" + dt.Columns[i].ColumnName + "]" + ",";
                else
                    SelectColumn += "[" + dt.Columns[i].ColumnName + "]";
            }

            
            
            SqlConnection myADONETConnection = new SqlConnection();
            myADONETConnection = (SqlConnection)(Dts.Connections["SnowFlakeDB"].AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction) as SqlConnection);


            TableName = "STG_PART_D_CUT_POINTS_RAW";
            string CreateTableStatement = "IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[" + SchemaName + "].";
            CreateTableStatement += "[" + TableName + "]')";
            CreateTableStatement += " AND type in (N'U'))DROP TABLE [" + SchemaName + "].";
            CreateTableStatement += "[" + TableName + "]  Create Table " + SchemaName + ".[" + TableName + "]";
            //CreateTableStatement += "([" + line.Replace(FileDelimiter, "] " + ColumnsDataType + ",[") + "] " + ColumnsDataType + ")";

            CreateTableStatement += "(ID int IDENTITY(1,1),[FileName] Varchar(70) Null," + ExcelHeaderColumn + ")";



            SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(CreateTableStatement, myADONETConnection);
            SqlCommand CreateTableCmd = sqlCommand;
            CreateTableCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            //MessageBox.Show(CreateTableStatement);

            //Use Columns to get data from Excel Sheet
            OleDbConnection cnn1 = new OleDbConnection(ConStr);
            cnn1.Open();
            //OleDbCommand oconn1 = new OleDbCommand("select"+ file.Name +" AS [FileName]," + SelectColumn + " from [" + sheetname + StartingColumn + StartReadingFromRow + ":" + EndingColumn + "]", cnn1);
            OleDbCommand oconn1 = new OleDbCommand("select '" + file.Name + "' AS [FileName]," + SelectColumn + " from [Part_D_Cut_Points$]", cnn1);
            OleDbDataAdapter adp1 = new OleDbDataAdapter(oconn1);
            DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
            adp1.Fill(dt1);
            cnn1.Close();


            //Load Data from DataTable to SQL Server Table.
            using (SqlBulkCopy BC = new SqlBulkCopy(myADONETConnection))
            {
                BC.DestinationTableName = SchemaName + "." + TableName;
                foreach (var column in dt1.Columns)
                    BC.ColumnMappings.Add(column.ToString(), column.ToString());
                BC.WriteToServer(dt1);
            }

            

            //}
            //}

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects...` statement is not valid SQL in Snowflake. Closest equivalent would be `CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE...`

Comment: Thanks Dave for comments and suggestion.  I have tried the what you have suggested and frame query according to snowflake environment in code but still it is giving me same error.

Comment: TableName = "STG_PART_D_CUT_POINTS_RAW";                
                string CreateTableStatement = "create or replace TABLE " + '"'+"US_DNA_Health_HPAAS" +'"'+"."+ SchemaName + "." + TableName;
                CreateTableStatement += "(ID int IDENTITY(1,1),FileName Varchar(70) Null," + ExcelHeaderColumn + ")";

  SqlCommand CreateTableCmd = new SqlCommand(CreateTableStatement,myADONETConnection);
                CreateTableCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: ExcelHeaderColumn is delimited with [ ]. For Snowflake, the delimiters should be " ".

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    String check = dt.Columns[i].ColumnName;

                    if (i != dt.Columns.Count - 1)
                        ExcelHeaderColumn += '"' + dt.Columns[i].ColumnName + '"' + " NVarchar(150) NULL" + ",";
                    else
                        ExcelHeaderColumn += '"' + dt.Columns[i].ColumnName + '"'+ " NVarchar(150) NULL";
                }

Comment: I have already changed the delimiters and after that applied break point on the create command statement and from console i copied and pasted create table query there in snowflake and it got executed successfully. But why it is not happening through  this CreateTableCmd.ExecuteNonQuery() statement